# Slugfy in filter sqlalchemy

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying slug some data, i use some `lower` and `replace` to change the special caracters i need:

my query is like this:

```
return Person.query.get(person_id).name.filter(func.lower(func.replace(Person.name, "ç", "c"))
```

works well,  but if i recive a other character like `á` or other special character, it's dosen't work.

Someone can tell me the best way to handle that, make a list of all special characters, or a sqlalchemy has a func to slug?

Answer (score 3):

You wouldn't be using lower and replace to slugify.
Try a library like: un33k/python-slugify (github).
In order to get the desired result, you can write something like:

```
from slugify import slugify
return Person.query.get(person_id).name.filter(slugify(Person.name))
```

I'm not so sure that your query is going to work, I only replaced the slug part and I recommend you to check it first.